# Multiple item lookup in GraphQL Query

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, graphql-java

I'm wondering what the most common approach to looking up multiple items based on ID is. From my naive understanding, I see 3 options:

## Option 1

Accept array of IDs and return all results

`products(ids: [ID!]!): [Product!]!`

This seems to be the most straightforward and intuitive approach, but doesn't allow clients to index into the results and strays from the pagination pattern other queries typically follow.

## Option 2

Force clients to use aliases

```
product(id: ID!): Product!
```

This is easiest to implement on the server side and also allows clients to index directly into the results based on the ID (assuming they use the ID as the alias), but also forces clients to construct more complex queries.

## Option 3

Accept array of IDs and return paginated results (via the Connection pattern)

```
products(ids: [ID!]!, after: String, first: Int! = 10): ProductConnection!
```

This stays consistent with other queries that return paginated results, but also has the same issue as #1 with not allowing clients to index directly into the results via the ID (assuming ID is used as the alias as in option 2). The connection pattern is also not immediately intuitive for users not familiar with it.

Any suggestions based on your experiences? Thanks!

Comment: I think you are covering all the ways here. I would like to mention that some people encurage queries that are build for views not for general querying. Also what _we_ would often do is have the Option 2 and Option 3 both in place and offer a more flexible filter parameter on the plural version e.g. `products(filter: { id: { in: [1, 2, 3] } })`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @Herku ! For the plural version, what are you returning? An array of products, or a connection? Also, are you using any library/framework for the filtering? Are there other "filters" you expose, other than `in`? Do you name the parameter something like `ProductFilterInput`? Appreciate the help!

Comment: I really don't understand all the hyper around graphQL. Why would something so simple require code to be written on server side... This tool is so far of being as magic as advertised. IMHO, graphQL is a DB DSL whose only purpose is to define authorization on what can be queried and how. But being able to query multiple elements instead of a single one, is like one of the most basic feature one can think of. Why is it needed to write more code on server side ? How is this even better than rest if you need to implement a server-side counterpart for something so basic... I don't get it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer is not neccesarily introducing more ways of doing things but I will elaborate some best practices that I have found for my schemas and how they relate to projects in the community.

### Option 2 is not viable with static queries

As I have already discussed in the comment think about what your app really needs. If you want to lookup a dynamic number of fields by ID *Option 2* is not going to be helpful when you want to use [static queries](https://blog.apollographql.com/5-benefits-of-static-graphql-queries-b7fa90b0b69a). You would have to be concatinating strings to create dynamic queries roughly like so:

```js
const query = `{ ${ids.map(id => `product${id}: product { ...Frag }\n`).join('')} }`;
```

This is a bad idea and the linked article talks about why and also your GraphQL endpoint is probably not made for it. We could as well send multiple queries one by one for each product but then we lose one of GraphQLs key advantages over REST.

**But:** We usually keep the field for querying single entities because viewing a single item is usually a use case of our app and we can very quickly respond to that query. See the last section of my answer on queries.

### The other two options are the same basically

*Option 1* and *Option 3* should just be chosen consistently across your project. The connection might not really be helpful when querying for IDs but it can prevent returning way to many items and seamlessly integrate with Relay.

You also need to consider how you then connect the IDs on the frontend with the values again. Do you return the items in the same order as queried (as know for example from Dataloader) or do you query the IDs of the entities and the order does not matter.

So if all your queries that return multiple items return connections then I would do it here as well. The danger is that queries will get to complex and this leads me to the last topic.

### Generic filters considered harmful

In general it is recommended to only expose queries that are really required by your frontend(s) as [this Twitter thread elaborates](https://twitter.com/freiksenet/status/1004316200715812869) and Lee Byron (one of the creators) adds [that you should also only expose queries that you can fulfill efficiently](https://twitter.com/leeb/status/1004655619431731200). In contrast Apollo recommends to [not couple clients and server implementations](https://principledgraphql.com/agility#4-abstract-demand-oriented-schema) and instead but abstract schemas. I think you will have to find a balance.

I think that exposing a filter object that is very specific is almost as good as creating a new field each time but it might not scale that well. You will quickly need to build complex queries and a query builder library might be helpful. On the other hand if you already have that in place - like in your example products might already be heavily filterable - it can be very easy to add.

Some project in the wild offer extensive filters like [Hasura](https://hasura.io/), [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/) and [Gatsby](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/). So if you want to build more generic filters you could take inspiration from these projects.

Comment: I'd love to know a bit more about the consequentes for client side caching for these approaches. Seems like option 2 might work out of the box (where a client doesn't repeat the same query, while option 1 and 3 will always have to query the whole list even if on id is different?

Comment: Well in theory you would not have to query the whole list but in practice the available caching solutions are not smart enough to handle this. If this turns out to be the bottleneck of your application you would probably need a special solution for this case.